# Firestore cloud doesn't save data from all users (js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, save

I have programmed an experiment using js and deploy it through firebase.

However I have noticed that the data of some participants is not stored, despite. I have only run three participants, i.e. 3 users on the website at the same time so I doubt it is due to it being overwhelmed and according to the documentation this shouldn't be a problem.

I know the page itself is working as the users all get redirected to another URL afterwards.

My concern then was that the save function was not executed quickly enough so I have included a minimum trial duration. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

I would appreciate any advice on this.

Thank you!

```
function saveData(data){
      console.log("trying to save");
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      var namedData = {};
      data.forEach(function(q) {  
      //console.log(q.internal_node_id) 
      if(q.hasOwnProperty("responses"))
      {
        q.responses = JSON.parse(q.responses);
      }
      namedData[q.internal_node_id] = q; 
    })
      //db.collection("user").doc(subject_id).set(namedData)
      db.collection("user").doc(subject_id).set(namedData)
        .then(function() {
          console.log("data saved")
        })
    }        
var saving = {
      type: 'html-keyboard-response',
      stimulus: "<p style='font-size: 24px;'>You have reached the end of this experiment. <br><br>Thank you for participating! <br><br> Please wait to be redirected to the next page. The data is saving. Do not press any key.",
      response_ends_trial:false,
      trial_duration: 5000,
      on_start: function() {(saveData(jsPsych.data.get().json()));
              },
    };
     // on_finish: function() {(saveData(jsPsych.data.get().json()));


    timeline.push(saving)
    
    var end = {
      type: 'html-keyboard-response',
      stimulus: "<p style='font-size: 24px;'>Please press any key to be redirected to Prolific.</p>",
      response_ends_trial:true,
      on_finish: function() {(window.location.replace("https://samplepagehere"))},
    };
```

Comment: By some data you mean, that for example only the userID is stored while the password is not? Also have you seen this only occur for the first, the last or the middle user? You can try loggin the information before sending it to firestore so you can confirm that the data is being sent correctly

Comment: @LouisC I have programmed an experiment - once participants have completed the experiment, the data gets stored. When I give each participant the url for the website they simply play it through and all their data should be stored. So let's say I have 10 participants I should then also have 10 datasets, but I only have 6. That is to say for some participants nothing is stored at all (incl.ID). It seems that whenever multiple participants are finishing at the same time this happens. Is it in fact true that firebase cannot save the data of 2+ participants/users at the same time?

Comment: Hello Lara firebase can support simultaneous connections https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits